# Why I am getting this error when i am trying to run this and getting the loss training?

Tags: python, pytorch

Why I am facing this error when I am trying to run this code below?
the error is in this section of the code (predictions.append(prd.item())) still not understand why its error?

```
train_accuracies = []
train_loss = []
predictions = []
for epoch in range(10):
    iterations = 0
    running_loss = 0
    for i,(inputs,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

        iterations+=1

        inputs = inputs.float()
        labels = labels.long()

        # Feed Forward
        output = net(inputs)
        # Loss Calculation
        loss = criterion(output, labels)

        running_loss = running_loss + loss.item()    
        _, prd = torch.max(output, dim = 1)
        predictions.append(prd.item())
        accuracy = (prd == labels).float().mean()
        train_accuracies.append(accuracy.item())
        train_loss.append(running_loss / iterations)

        #i = i.view(i.shape[0], -1)

        # Clear the gradient buffer (we don't want to accumulate gradients)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Backpropagation 
        loss.backward()
        # Weight Update: w <-- w - lr * gradient
        optimizer.step()



        #print("Epoch [{}][{}/{}], Loss: {:.3f}".format(epoch, i, len(train_loader), running_loss / iterations))
        print("Epoch [{}][{}/{}], Loss: {:.3f}".format(epoch ,i , len(train_loader), running_loss))
```

The error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-41-8bf6c94dc5dd> in <module>()
     19         running_loss = running_loss + loss.item()
     20         _, prd = torch.max(output, dim = 1)
---> 21         predictions.append(prd.item())
     22         accuracy = (prd == labels).float().mean()
     23         train_accuracies.append(accuracy.item())

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `.item()` only works with scalar tensors. i.e. tensors with only one element. In your case `prd` has one entry for each item in your batch.

Comment: @jodag okay so you mean I have to change the batch size into only 1 or use another way? I mean change `(itme())` into another one so what do you recommend me for this?

Comment: Depends on your goal. Trying to interpret the broken code I would guess you want to either delete the line `predictions.append(prd.item())` since you're not using it in the code you posted or you could replace it with something like `predictions.extend(prd.tolist())`.